# why angular child route not rendering component except first time?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I have few component in my angular project. And child route to render those component in one special component. When I click to route it render component for the first time. But after that it only change url parameter but not rendering any component.

Here is my code,

course.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="courses">
  <a *ngFor="let course of courses" class="btn btn-danger" color="warn" routerLink="{{ course.id }}">{{ course.title }}</a>
</div>
```

course.component.ts

```
segmentId: Object;
courses: Object;
meta_data: any;
showSpinner: boolean = true;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private data: DataService, private seo: SeoService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.segmentId = this.route.snapshot.params['segment'];
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.segmentId = params.segment
    });

    this.data.getCourses(this.segmentId).subscribe(data => {
        this.courses = data[0].courses;

        this.meta_data = data[0];

        this.showSpinner = false;

        //console.log( this.courses )
        //console.log( this.meta_data.segmentName )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is only called once per component instantiation. So it is the normal behaviour.

If you want changes in real time, you need to use observable like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap(params => {
      this.segmentId = params.get('segment');
      return this.data.getCourses(this.segmentId);
    })
  ).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.courses = data[0].courses;
      this.meta_data = data[0];
      this.showSpinner = false;
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Cannot find switchMap

Comment: you have to import the operator: `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`